# Why does my cat shed so much?

Tags: cats, shedding

My cat, Odin, sheds a lot. He mostly sheds when he is nervous, aggressive, or play fighting with my other cat, Bose. Is this a problem? I don't really know what's going on with him. He also seems to shed when he is very scared, and I find a lot of hairs from my cat all around the house.

My other cat, Bose, doesn't shed as often, though.

I searched, and it said that my cat can have a bunch of different medical issues, including stress, poor diet, and allergies. I think the closest medical issue it could be is stress. He seems very aggressive and nervous a lot, so maybe that's it?

It also said to brush my cat daily, but almost every day, I forget to brush his hair. So it could be that, as well. My cat doesn't fight a lot with my other cat.

Maybe it has something to do with their breeds? Odin is an American Shorthair, and Bose is a Bombay.

So why do you think my cat, Odin, sheds a lot?

Comment: If this is obviously more than seasonal transition shedding, include a photo. Make sure it covers balding spots if your cat has any. I don't really have a good answer for this, but there are some vets and vet students around who can give a good answer. Also, any hair loss is much noticeable in black cats, so it might just be nothing :)

Comment: @FH Jordan "American Shorthair" the purebred breed, or "Domestic shorthair from America," the generic "cat?"

Comment: @C.Koca  it's my AMERICAN SHORTHAIR that's shedding a lot. And yes, it is near shedding "Season", and my cat is losing a bit more hair. But he even sheds a lot other that that.

Comment: @FHJordan is it the purebred or the generic?

Comment: Bombay cats are low-shedders with relatively fine fur (less noticeable when it does shed), so I would expect most other cats to shed more than a Bombay cat. Do you have experience living with other cats besides these two, to compare to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the disclaimer I am not a vet, but from your description, I do get the impression the shedding could be stress related, specifically due to these points:

- It visibly increases in specific situations. Normal shedding is usually pretty consistent, with an exception for if the cat is being petted or groomed, which tends to pull out loose hairs.
- The cat seems generally anxious and aggressive. Keep in mind, aggression is often rooted in anxiety as well.

**Take the cat to the vet.**

Even though stress seems a likely cause, it's probably a good idea to make sure there really is no medical explanation for the unusual shedding. While you are there, I would also bring up the possibility of giving the cat anxiety medication. If it turns out the shedding really is stress related, then it's likely a sign the cat has unusual levels of anxiety. A cat at home in its regular routine should not be showing signs of stress. It's also possible anxiety medication will make the cat less aggressive.

It is also possible though that it's simply due to differences between individual cats. In this case, there's nothing really to worry about, other than having to clean up more hair, and being careful about hairballs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your cat is stressed. During this time, the follicles of certain hairs called telogen hairs are released. The discharge causes the cat to shed more than usual.
I have had cats for 5 years. I often notice their changes and learn from them. Their hair loss worries me because when they lose their hair they fly all over the house and even get on their clothes which makes me very uncomfortable. I have found that the reasons they lose so much can be due to age, being too stressed, or being pregnant, and especially when they shed seasonally the hair tends to fall out a lot. a lot of.
I  found many solutions to the problem, you can brush your cat daily, bathe her from time to time, be consistent in her diet and remember to check your cat.

Comment: what is the reason for giving the cat a bath?it has no effect on the shedding problem and if the cat shed as a result of stress then i think your sugestion might be counterproductive.

Comment: Do you have any sources that you can add to your answer?

Comment: Please don't just add a link to a random website; links can change and sites can disappear, leaving part of your answer inaccessible to future viewers. We want long-lasting answers here, so I've rolled back the change to add the link; if you'd like to use information from that site, please add it to the body of the question with appropriate citations, so it's protected from "link rot." Thanks!